# How to send a [String] in a Get Request in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, get, request

I am trying to send a exPID = `["abcdef"]` is an array containing one String in Swift GET Request using :

```
request(URLInfo, method: .get, parameters: exPID, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: getHeader)
```

but parameters are expecting a Dictionary of String:AnyObject.

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type
> 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>')

I also tried `getRequest.httpbody`. It is giving me error even then.

Comment: Welcome! Please, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly and then clarify what do you need. `["abcdef"]` is an array containing one string. How the URL should look like? `&exPID=abcdef` (like the array in the question is a mistake) or you'd like to have multiple values `&exPID=abcdef&exPID=qwewqe` (this array is not a mistake), ... or the parameter value should include these square brackes & quotes as well?

Comment: expId = ["abcdef"] is an array containing only one string.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a String for Example "ExPID" in the http body has been outlawed for GET Request having a body. This change was called out in iOS 13.0 release notes.

```
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123348
```

That's why Swift will automatically fails such request as "**GET method must not have a body"**

This can be done only by sending a Parameter such as key and value using AlamoFire or sending a String in POST Request.